# The slope of the tangent to the curve $10x^3+5x^2y+4xy^2+6y^3=25$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am having problems understanding how to solve this equation:

The slope of the tangent to the curve:
 $$10x^3+5x^2y+4xy^2+6y^3=25$$
at the point $(1,1)$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with implicit differentiation?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{F'_{x}}{F'_{y}}=\dfrac{30x^2+10xy+4y^2}{5x^2+8xy+18y^2}$$
so
$$y'_{x}|_{x=1}=-\dfrac{44}{31}$$
then the tangent
$$y-1=-\dfrac{44}{31}(x-1)$$
where
$$F=10x^3+5x^2y+4xy^2+6y^3-25$$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating wrt $x$, $$30x^2+\left(10xy+5x^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+\left(4y^2+8xy\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+18y^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$$
At $(1, 1)$, this gives $30+10+5y'+4+8y'+18y'=0$, so what is $y'$?

Answer (score 0):

After differentiating and finding an expression for $y'$, once you put the given values of $(1,1)$ for $(x,y)$, your answer will be $-44/31$.

Comment: Not very helpful, I would say.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to this place and yet to learn how to use LaTeX

Comment: This [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should help you learn how to use LaTeX.